# Compare two identical tables, move the updated row from table 1 to table 2 without deleting in table 2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two identical tables 'Table 1' and 'Table 2', 'Table 2' has an addition column 'status'.

I have 3 similar records in both the tables 1 and 2. for all the three records in the table 2 the status is set to '1'.

I updated one of the record in table 1. I wish to move the updated record to table 2 as a new record in the table 2 with the status as '1' and also set the previous record in table 2 set to '0'.

How do i compare the two tables for an modified record?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: First of is this SQL Server or MySQL?!

Comment: You'll probably need a trigger or possibly replication but it's not really clear what you want to achieve. Could you add some more info (say do you want the "compare" to happen as soon as the update is done, can both tables be updated etc)

Comment: @Zane title said SQLServer so I removed MySql tag.

Comment: For future reference OP MySQL <> SQL that is mine and SQL Server <> SQL that happens to be running on a Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can user the tool offered by [RED GATE DATA COMPARE](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/), or just make you query using this syntax:

```
SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 
    FROM (
        SELECT [Table A] as TableName, A.ID, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3
        FROM A
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [Table B] as TableName, B.ID, B.COL1, B.COl2, B.COL3
        FROM B
    ) tmp
    GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ORDER BY ID
```